# IIS & ASP.NET blocking file

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have an ASP.NET app running in IIS that is hosting files all great but it blocks all *.upd files and says http 404.

If I turn directory listing on it lists the file just great but I cant download it any way...

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to configure IIS to serve your file type as it won't serve unknown ones: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326965

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the .upd file type to the IIS Mime Types. You can do this through:

- Launch IIS MMC
- Right Click -> Properties on machine
  name node
- Click Mime Types button
- Click 'New'
- Enter the 'Extension' (in this case
  .upd')
- Enter the Mime Type (you need to find
  out the type, if you're not sure try
  `application/octet-stream`, it's
  always a good bet).
- Click OK and close all dialogues.

The file should then be downloadable.