# I cannot access files in IIS 6

Tags: iis

I have a default IIS 6 install and I can access only .html files. If I create a html file I can see it on the browser. Any other files like ini for example are not visible (404). Any idea on what can be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check the web service extensions are enabled (in IIS below the websites is a folder for them) for the content you are trying to share.
2. Check that the handler mappings is setup correctly (on the website properties)

Answer (score 1):

This may help :

[IIS & ASP.NET blocking file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506744/iis-asp-net-blocking-file)